# How to use the same function for multiple HTMLElement events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, function, object, this

I have 2 buttons. I want to be able to click on one of them and change only his value attribute. The code snippet below works, but only for the second object. I've tried with (obj1|| obj2) but that doesn't work either. Please help

```
(obj1,obj2).onclick = function this_test (){
    this.value = "new value"
};
```

Comment: Incidentally, the reason your example only works on the second object is because the comma operator evaluates both sides and throws away the left result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var clickFunction = function() {
    this.value = "new value";
};

obj1.onclick = clickFunction;
obj2.onclick = clickFunction;
```

[**Example showing `this` representing the clicked item**](http://jsfiddle.net/ap64k/), even though they share the function.

Comment: thank you. so there is no way to evade this 
obj1.onclick = clickFunction;
obj2.onclick = clickFunction;
and write this in a single line?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this, `obj1.onclick = obj2.onclick = clickFunction;` but it is really a terrible way to do it, an extra line to keep your code easily readable is far worth the expense of the extra line.